# Umbraco log file giving (404) Not Found error every minute

Tags: logging, https, url-rewriting, umbraco7, virtual-directory

We have a site that we created using Umbraco version 7.2.4.  It is setup in IIS 7 as a virtual directory as /home.  It has to be setup as a virtual directory since other company sites depend on this being a virtual directory.  We also have a URL Rewrite setup on IIS that redirects anything from HTTP to HTTPS.  The following is the rewrite rule that IIS created in the root web.config file:

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

The HTTP and HTTPS bindings have also been set in IIS.

The umbraco log files keeps giving the following message about every minute:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
   at System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.HomogenizeErrors(Func`2 func, Byte[] input)
   at System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(String encryptedTicket)
   at Umbraco.Core.StringExtensions.DecryptWithMachineKey(String value)
   at Umbraco.Web.Mvc.AdminTokenAuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
2015-08-11 10:57:02,376 [7] ERROR Umbraco.Web.Scheduling.ScheduledPublishing - [Thread 14] An error occurred with the scheduled publishing. The base url used in the request was: https://www.xyzsite.com/home/umbraco/, see http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Using-Umbraco/Config-files/umbracoSettings/#ScheduledTasks documentation for details on setting a baseUrl if this is in error
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
   at Umbraco.Web.Scheduling.ScheduledPublishing.Run()
```

We set "umbracoUseSSL" to "true" in the web.config and we set the scheduledTasks tag in the umbracoSettings.config to the following:

```
  <scheduledTasks baseUrl="www.xyzsite.com/home/umbraco">

  </scheduledTasks>
```

The site does run as expected except that I cannot log into the site using /home/umbraco.  The browser just gives me a blank screen after logging in.  We created another IIS application that points to the same location that can only be accessed internally so that we can access the admin page, but the log file keeps filling up with this same error message.

Has anyone else ran across this issue with their log file?  Is there some way this should be configured differently?

Comment: Make sure to upgrade to 7.2.8 where this was fixed.

Comment: Thanks.  We upgraded our dev and qa environments from 7.2.4 to 7.2.8 and are cautiously optimistic that the upgrade has helped resolve this issue.  We did set umbracoUseSSL to false in the web.config and removed the baseUrl attribute from the scheduledTasks tag in the umbracoSettings.config file.